# Select where json contains

Tags: json, postgresql

I have a postgres table:

```
      Column      |          Type           
------------------+------------------------+
 id               | bigint                 |
 foo_id           | integer                |
 foo_name         | character varying(255) |
 bar_id           | json                   |
```

With values

```
     id |      foo_id    |       foo_name                |             bar_id
--------+----------------+-------------------------------+----------------------------
     17 |         717639 | name 1                        | [910, 5383774, 437, 5350]
     18 |        8442028 | name 2                        | [7274, 6241861, 437, 73669939]
     19 |          77415 | name n                        | [7274, 5513, 249642574, 743181502]
```

How can I select from this table records ids where bar_id contains value 437?

Comment: please share your attempt

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the operator `@>` to check if the array contains a specific value.

However that only works with `jsonb` values, not `json` values. So you need to cast your column.

```
select *
from the_table
where bar_id:jsonb @> '[437]';
```

It would be better to change the column's type to `jsonb`.